# why in this chance constraint we have convexity?

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, convex-cone

I havea chance constraint of the form 
$$ \mathbb{P}[a^\text{T}x\leqslant b]\geqslant\alpha$$
where $b\in\mathbb{R}$ is fixed, $a\in\mathbb{R}^n$ is a vector whose entries are Independent and identically distributed ,  and normally distributed with mean $\overline{a}$ and variance $\Sigma$

(that is, $a\sim\mathcal{N}(\overline{a},\Sigma)$), and $\alpha>1/2$ . It is well known that this constraint is equivalent to
$$ F^{-1}(\alpha)\|\Sigma^{1/2}x\|_2\leqslant-\overline{a}^\text{T}x+b $$

why if $\alpha>1/2$ , then  $\  \  F^{-1}(\alpha)\|\Sigma^{1/2}x\|_2$ is a convex?

Comment: Because $F^{-1}(\alpha) > 0$ for $\alpha > \frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: @madnessweasley  I know $F^{-1}(\alpha)\>0  if \alpha >0.5 $ , I do not know the convexity of this $|\Sigma^{1/2}x\||_2 $

Comment: Read a proof as to why second order cones are convex.

Comment: @ LinAlg thanks for your help

Comment: @LinAlg i searched " proof second order cones are convex." but i cant find anything , can you give me a link , site or book ,?

Comment: it follows from https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2280341/why-is-every-p-norm-convex

Comment: @LinAlg thank you , so if $\alpha >0.5$ and we have every norm in $ ||\Sigma ^{0.5 } x||_p$

We have convexity too .