# $p$-norm is sub-modular

Tags: functional-analysis, convex-analysis, normed-spaces

For all $p \geq 1$, $p$-norm is defined as,
$$\Vert{x}\Vert_p=\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n} \vert{x_i}\vert^p\right)^{1/p}.$$

In this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2280341/why-is-every-p-norm-convex), it has been shown that "every $p$-norm function is convex" for $x\in\Bbb{R}^n$. I failed to prove for $x\in\Bbb{Z}^n$, which results in "every $p$-norm function is sub-modular."

Comment: What is your definition of a sub-modular function? Wikipedia defines them as set functions: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Submodular_set_function

Comment: I think I should direct you to this http://people.csail.mit.edu/stefje/fall15/notes_lecture9.pdf.